# Pydantic from_orm to load Django model with related list field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, pydantic

I have the following Django models:

```py
from django.db import models


class Foo(models.Model):
    id: int
    name = models.TextField(null=False)


class Bar(models.Model):
    id: int
    foo = models.ForeignKey(
        Foo,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        related_name="bars",
    )
```

And Pydantic models (with `orm_mode` set to `True`):

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class BarPy(BaseModel):
    id: int
    foo_id: int


class FooPy(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    bars: list[BarPy]
```

Now I want to perform a query on the model `Foo` and load it into `FooPy`, so i wrote this query:

```py
foo_db = Foo.objects.prefetch_related("bars").all()
pydantic_model = FooPy.from_orm(foo_db)
```

But it gives me this error:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for FooPy
  bars
    value is not a valid list (type=type_error.list)
```

I am able to do it when explicitly using the `FooPy` constructor and assigning the values manually but i want to use `from_orm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bars` attribute on your `Foo` model is a [`ReverseManyToOneDescriptor`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.1.4/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L546) that just returns a `RelatedManager` for the `Bar` model. As with any manager in Django, to get a queryset of all the instances managed by it, you need to call the `all` method on it. Typically you would do something like `foo.bars.all()`.

You can add your own custom [validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/) to `FooPy` and make it `pre=True` to grab all the related `Bar` instances and pass a sequence of them along to the default validators:

```py
from django.db.models.manager import BaseManager
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

...

class FooPy(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    bars: list[BarPy]

    @validator("bars", pre=True)
    def get_all_from_manager(cls, v: object) -> object:
        if isinstance(v, BaseManager):
            return list(v.all())
        return v
```

Note that it is not enough to just do `.all()` because that will return a queryset, which will not pass the default sequence validator built into Pydantic models. You would get the same error.

You need to give it an actual sequence (e.g. `list` or `tuple`). A `QuerySet` is not a sequence, but an iterable. But you can consume it and turn it into a sequence, by calling for example `list` on it.

---

#### More generalized version

You could make an attempt at generalizing that validator and add it to your own (Pydantic) base model. Something like this should work on any field you annotate as `list[Model]`, with `Model` being a subclass of `pydantic.BaseModel`:

```py
from django.db.models.manager import BaseManager
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from pydantic.fields import ModelField, SHAPE_LIST

...

class CustomBaseModel(BaseModel):

    @validator("*", pre=True)
    def get_all_from_manager(cls, v: object, field: ModelField) -> object:
        if not (isinstance(field.type_, type) and issubclass(field.type_, BaseModel)):
            return v
        if field.shape is SHAPE_LIST and isinstance(v, BaseManager):
            return list(v.all())
        return v
```

I have not thoroughly tested this, but I think you get the idea.

---

#### Side note

It is worth mentioning that `prefetch_related` has nothing to do with the problem. The problem and its solution are the same, whether you do that or not. The difference is that without `prefetch_related`, you'll trigger additional database queries, when calling `from_orm` and thus executing the validator that consumes the queryset of `.bars.all()`.